# validation pattern in ValidationExpression of asp.net webform: required at least one digit

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, webforms

so I have to validate a pattern that support only lower and upper case character and must have `at least one digit`, must between range of 8 to 16.

so far I have

```
ValidationExpression="(^[A-Za-z0-9](?=.*\d){8,16})$"
```

that seems not working, any hint ?

i.e.

```
abcdef will not work 
abcdef12 will work
```

Comment: Do you mean that the second string should be valid? There are spaces and 2 digits instead of 1. Or did you mean, lowercase, uppercase, at least one digit and white spaces?

Comment: Is a length between 8 and 16 characters also a requirement?

Comment: @Michelle Yup, and this constraint too that I overlooked!

Comment: @Michelle Yes, didnt include it at first time

Comment: So it may only contain lower- and uppercase letters and digits (alphanumeric), must be 8-16 characters, and must contain at least one digit? Is this correct?

Comment: @Michelle: yes, there is solution down below works fine now

Comment: @cool_spirit - you should check off the answer that you used to complete this question.

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem:**

`(^[A-Za-z0-9](?=.*\d){8,16})$`

This is looking for a match within your string that:
- contains a single item out of `[A-Za-z0-9]`
- has a look-ahead of `.*\d`,  the lookahead hapening`8-16` times.

**Possible Solutions:**

Put the `{8,16}` on `[A-Za-z0-9]` rather than the look-ahead, and then move the look-ahead to the front:

```
^(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]{8,16}$
```

Also, if you wish to have atleast one of each capital and lowercase letters, you can do this:

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,16})$
```

Comment: Wouldn't the first condition still match if the string starts with a digit? The .* would match nothing and then the \d would match the first character, no?

Comment: @smerny: yes, I wonder know what is the difference between (?:(?=.*\d) or (?:(?=\d.*)

Comment: @Michelle - You appear to be correct, I'm not sure what I was thinking at the time, I removed the second

Answer (score 1):

I would check the requirements and constraints separately. So first, you would check that the input is alphanumeric and the right length:

```
ConstraintsExpression="^([A-Za-z\d]){8,16}$"
```

Then, check that there's at least one digit:

```
RequirementsExpression="\d"
```

There's no `^` or `$` in the second regex, because you want to be able to find it anywhere in the input. If it matches at all, there's at least one digit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this regex if you mean the string should have only uppercase letters, lowercase letters and at least one digit, and lastly between the required length:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,16}$
```

If it's for passwords, I'm not sure why it should have only alphanumeric characters. Adding symbols in make passwords stronger!

To allow any characters, and at the same time make sure there's at least one digit, one lowercase and one uppercase, you can use this:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$
```

Will allow creation of passwords like `P@$5W0rd`.